# Windows console api

Tags: c, windows, winapi, console

I'm not that experienced in windows programming and want to know what api windows uses for making a text user interface in c, the way that ncurses does on unix-based systems.  Is it part of the win32 api?  Where can I get more information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the [windows console api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682087.aspx).

And, you can always get [ncurses for windows](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/).